# How to execute command on DataGridTextColumn's Text click

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with multiple columns. One column should be used as a reference, but it behaves like a dummy text now. How to execute any command by clicking on this text using the MVVM pattern (without events)?

```
<DataGridTextColumn
    Binding="{Binding RecipeName}"
    Header="Recipe"
    Width="1.5*"/>
```

[image: Make A-0603 clickable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use a button in your cells by redefining the CellTemplate of your column.

Here's an example :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- Your first column -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Recipe">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <!-- Let's redefine the cell template for our column -->
                <ItemContainerTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding RecipeName}" Command="{Binding MyCommand}">
                        <!-- Here we remove the button's default templating by overriding it -->
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </ItemContainerTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```